# How to redirect url after setting cookie using express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, authentication

This is my login code in express router:

```
if (password === realpassword) {
    res.cookie('thecookie', 'somethingliketoken');
    res.redirect(302, '/somepages');
} else {
    res.status(403).end();
}
```

I want to set the cookie so that the `/somepages` can recognize who is this user.

But I got error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

I had already tried `return res.redirect(302, '/somepages');`. The query to `/somepages` had be sent correctly but the page still stayed in my `/login`.

Please help.

Comment: I tried the same snippet of code, it's redirecting like charm, I will need your code to debug

Comment: the problem is that you can't send two responses at a time on one route.

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya res.cookie() is just setting the cookie, not sending the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the reason.
I posted the username and password using AJAX so the 302 redirect was sent to the AJAX query and yes it redirected successfully but **it was for the AJAX query**, not for the page, that was why the second query was received but the page didn't change.

```
          this.$http({
                url: '/userLogin',
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    username: this.username,
                    password: SHA3(this.password, {outputLength: 256}).toString(),
                },
            }).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                this.hintColor = '#00bdd8';
                this.hint = 'success';
            }).catch(err => {
                this.hintColor = 'red';
                if (err.response.status == 403) {
                    this.hint = 'mismatch';
                } else {
                    this.hint = '500err';
                }
            });
```

I think it may should not be used like this.

Will using `window.location` instead.

If there are any other ways,  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this in my login post request, and its working for me.

```
app.post('/index',function(req,res){
  var uname = req.body.Username;
  var pwd = req.body.Password;
  if(uname && pwd === 'admin'){
    var token = jwt.sign( { username: uname }, 'q1W2e3R4t5Y6u7I8o9P',{ expiresIn: '1m' }
      );
    res.cookie('auth',token);
    res.redirect('home');
    console.log('Authentication is done successfully.....');
    console.log(token);
  }
});
```